# problem in starting camera?

Tags: blackberry

hie i am using jde 4.5 want to use camera through my app.
i write the code and getting runtime excepetion Pushmodelscreen caaled by non event thread
tell me what the problem in it?

public void start Camera()

```
 {
  try {
// Create a player for the Blackberry's camera
Player player= Manager.createPlayer( "capture://video" );
     // Set the player to the REALIZED state (see Player javadoc)
         player.realize();
         // Grab the video control and set it to the current display
         _videoControl = (VideoControl)player.getControl( "VideoControl" );
         if (_videoControl != null)
         {
             // Create the video field as a GUI primitive (as opposed to a
             // direct video, which can only be used on platforms with
             // LCDUI support.)
             _videoField = (Field) _videoControl.initDisplayMode (VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");
             _videoControl.setDisplayFullScreen(true);
             _videoControl.setVisible(true);
         }
         player.start();
         if(_videoField!=null)
      {
       add(_videoField);
      }
```

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Dialog.alert(e.getMessage());
   }
     }
`

thnaks alot
Amit

Comment: `Pushmodelscreen caaled by non event thread`

This error usually occurs when a pop up screen or `Dialog.alert` needs to be displayed before any screen is pushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that involved in UI changes should be called from within the UI thread. So most likely some part of your code should be called in a way:

```
UIApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do your UI related staff here
        // e.g. push a Screen or call Dialog.alert(), etc.
    }
});
```

Also, you may find [this info](http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/182) interesting.